# It is possible to insert for loop in ftp script?

Tags: bash, ftp

I want to put in for-loop in the ftp script. My code is as follows.

```
ftp -n ftp.server.com <<EOF
    user name passwd
    bin
    prompt
    for DATA in d f g l m n o p q; do
        mkdir /directory/$DATA
        cd /directory/$DATA
        mput *.$DATA
    done
    hash
    bye
EOF
```

It's not working and error is

```
Interactive mode off.
We only support non-print format, sorry.
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
Create directory operation failed.
local: mput: No such file or directory
(local-files) ?Invalid command
Hash mark printing on (1024 bytes/hash mark).
```

Of course I can put this ftp script in for loop, inversely. Is there anything good advice?

Comment: are you trying upload/download many files in one session thus the loop or you are just trying to automate it through script ?

Comment: Yes, I want to upload files into some directories, respectively.

Comment: can you try with this option ( ftp -n -v ) and see if it omits more in a log and also check with prompt off

Comment: Also in your log it says 'Create directory failed' .. are you trying to create directory on remote server ?

Comment: You can't put a loop inside `ftp`, it doesn't have any scripting commands like that. You can instead write a loop that uses `curl` or `wget`

Comment: @IndraUprade Yes, I do. I edited my post so you can see the problems. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I see. Thanks, that's what I want to know.

Comment: Or you can write like this: `{ echo user name passwd; echo bin; echo prompt; for .... do ... done; echo hash; echo bye;  } | ftp -n ftp.server.com`

Comment: @anishsane Make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `bash` loop inside `ftp` prompt. But you can generate the `stdin` for `ftp` via a bash loop.

```
{ 
    echo username passwd
    echo bin
    echo prompt
    for DATA in d f g l m n o p q; do
        echo mkdir /directory/$DATA
        echo cd /directory/$DATA
        echo mput *.$DATA
    done
    echo hash
    echo bye
} | ftp -n ftp.server.com
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works, please?

Comment: `ftp` can be run as an interactive process that can accept commands over `stdin`. You can generate the commands via simple echo and feed it to ftp.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to upload all files to remote server which are created/modified today.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'

# Local directory where the files are stored.
cd "/local/directory/from where to upload files/"

# To get all the files added today only.
TODAYSFILES=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1`


# remote server directory to upload backup
REMOTEDIR="/directory on remote ftp computer/"

for FILENAME in ${TODAYSFILES[@]}; do
  ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
  ascii
  user $USER $PASSWD
  prompt
  cd $REMOTEDIR
  put $FILENAME
  bye
  EOT
done
```